# Python Pandas Group by date using datetime data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

I have a datetime column `Date_Time` that I wish to groupby without creating a new column. Is this possible? I tried the following and it does not work.

```
df = pd.groupby(df,by=[df['Date_Time'].date()])
```

Answer (score 90, accepted):

#### [`resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

```
df.resample('D', on='Date_Time').mean()

              B
Date_Time      
2001-10-01  4.5
2001-10-02  6.0
```

---

#### [`Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

As suggested by @JosephCottam

```
df.set_index('Date_Time').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).mean()

              B
Date_Time      
2001-10-01  4.5
2001-10-02  6.0
```

---

#### Deprecated uses of `TimeGrouper`

You can set the index to be `'Date_Time'` and use `pd.TimeGrouper`

```
df.set_index('Date_Time').groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).mean().dropna()

              B
Date_Time      
2001-10-01  4.5
2001-10-02  6.0
```

Comment: This is great! How do i prevent it from adding dates that there are no data for? For example if i had data for days 9/1,9/2,and 9/4 it still has 9/3 in there with NaN values.

Comment: @GoBlue_MathMan Use `.dropna()`

Comment: Here, when grouping by 'hour', it adds hours that did not exist in the source file with zero values.

Comment: You can avoid `.set_index('Date_Time')` by doing `pd.Grouper(key='Date_Time', freq='D')`. Could be useful if the index is significant.

Answer (score 104):

You can use `groupby` by dates of column `Date_Time` by [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
df = df.groupby([df['Date_Time'].dt.date]).mean()
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date_Time': pd.date_range('10/1/2001 10:00:00', periods=3, freq='10H'),
                   'B':[4,5,6]})

print (df)
   B           Date_Time
0  4 2001-10-01 10:00:00
1  5 2001-10-01 20:00:00
2  6 2001-10-02 06:00:00

print (df['Date_Time'].dt.date)
0    2001-10-01
1    2001-10-01
2    2001-10-02
Name: Date_Time, dtype: object

df = df.groupby([df['Date_Time'].dt.date])['B'].mean()
print(df)
Date_Time
2001-10-01    4.5
2001-10-02    6.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Another solution  with [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Date_Time').resample('D')['B'].mean()

print(df)
Date_Time
2001-10-01    4.5
2001-10-02    6.0
Freq: D, Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 7):

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Date_Time', axis=0, freq='M')).sum()
```

- M for month
- Y for year
- D for day

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).