# Cannot group dates to get mean value in Pandas due to time stamps

Tags: python-3.x, pandas-groupby

[image: Trying to get the mean sentiment by day, but cannot figure it out.]

I have a list of tweet sentiment values and the timestamps of the tweets. I want to get the daily mean values, but I cannot get rid of the timestamp values so my groupby is not working.

Comment: Is `Date` stored as string or as datetime ? If it's a string, convert it into datetime. You will be able to filter the df then. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32204631/how-to-convert-string-to-datetime-format-in-pandas-python) if you want to know more about coneverting string to datetime.

Comment: The Date column type is a pandas series. My goal is to have only the date values exist so I can groupby the mean value per day.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

initial df:

```py
    Date                        Sentiment
0   2020-01-31 00:00:00+00:00   0.6369
1   2020-01-31 01:00:00+00:00   0.3612
```

**Code:**

```py
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], utc=False)
df['Date']=df['Date'].dt.date

df.groupby('Date')['Sentiment'].mean()
```

**Output:**

```py
Date
2020-01-31    0.49905
Name: Sentiment, dtype: float64
```

final df:

```py
    Date        Sentiment
0   2020-01-31  0.6369
1   2020-01-31  0.3612
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400136/5822871

df = df.groupby([df['Date_Time'].dt.date]).mean()