# Using time series data in a pandas dataframe in Python, how can I calculate a sum for columns that have the same date

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I'm not very good at formulating questions so I'm sorry for the title. I hope this example is specific enough; if I have a python pandas dataframe (df) that holds the following data:

```
Date          Num
01-01-2020    2
01-02-2020    4
01-01-2020    8
01-02-2020    16
```

how do I add up all of the 'Num' columns that have the same date so the df would look like this:

```
Date          Num
01-01-2020    10
01-02-2020    20
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas Group by date using datetime data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400115/python-pandas-group-by-date-using-datetime-data)

Comment: `df.groupby("Date").sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

df.groupby("Date").sum()

should do it, thank you Henry Yik