# How can I get the last 10 records of each day?

Tags: python, time-series, timestamp

I have a DataFrame with 96 records each day, for 5 consecutive days.

**Data:**  {'value': {Timestamp ('2018-05-03 00:07:30'): 13.02657778, Timestamp ('2018-05-03 00:22:30'): 10.89890556, Timestamp ('2018-05-03 00:37:30'): 11.04877222,... (more days and times)

**Datatypes:** DatetimeIndex (index column) and float64 ('flow' column).

I want to save 10 records before an indicated hour (H), of each day.

I only managed to do that for one day:

```
df.loc[df['time'] < '09:07:30'].tail(10)
```

Comment: pls try this `df.groupby('time').tail(10)`

Comment: Don't work. Returns all of the rows of the initial dataset. Thk
(Note that my code line is wrong because it assumes that the time is a column)

Comment: I think you need to put some filter before groupby, so added it as an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group your data by day (or by month or by other ranges) using [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) (see also [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400115/python-pandas-group-by-date-using-datetime-data)).

In your case, use something like:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).tail(10)
```

**EDIT:**

For getting all rows before a given hour, use `df.loc[df.index.hour < H]` (as already proposed in simpleApp's answer) where *H* is the hour as an integer value.

So in one line:

```
df.loc[df.index.hour < H].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).tail(10)
```

Comment: It works, but only just save the last 10 records of each day. I want to save 10 records before an indicated hour (H).

Comment: @catsandc: You seemed to already have a solution to to this (in your question). Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest filter the record by an hour and then group by date.

**Data setup:**

```
import pandas as pd
start, end = '2020-10-01 01:00:00', '2021-04-30 23:30:00'
rng = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='5min')
df=pd.DataFrame(rng,columns=['DateTS'])
```

set the hour

```
noon_hour=12 # fill the hour , for filteration
```

Result, if head or tail does not work on your data, you would need to sort it.

```
df_before_noon=df.loc[df['DateTS'].dt.hour < noon_hour] # records before noon
df_result=df_before_noon.groupby([df_before_noon['DateTS'].dt.date]).tail(10) # group by date
```