# Get the yearly average with Pandas Dateframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a 396 rows x 5 columns of monthly values between 1/1/1990 and 12/1/2022.

```
          time        KW       KWB      KWNB    KW_Wan
0   1990-01-01  6.202622  4.703502  1.364310  1.094818
1   1990-02-01  5.496127  4.105197  1.315037  0.994010
2   1990-03-01  5.709514  4.271940  1.337316  0.962968
3   1990-04-01  5.462525  4.046974  1.304561  0.892898
4   1990-05-01  5.962263  4.497025  1.317582  0.978504
..         ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
391 2022-08-01  6.344508  4.833736  1.342924  1.024887
392 2022-09-01  6.186552  4.686499  1.358012  0.975839
393 2022-10-01  5.886825  4.411931  1.343506  1.000438
394 2022-11-01  5.511992  4.101947  1.303725  0.962535
395 2022-12-01  5.858962  4.398572  1.364262  0.987936
```

I'd like to compute the annual mean for each column so I'd end up with a 32 x 5 data frame. I tried using this line of code:

```
year=pd.Series(range(1990,2023))
a_kw=monthlymean_kw.groupby(monthlymean_kw.time.dt.year)['KW'].transform('mean')
a_kwb=monthlymean_kw.groupby(monthlymean_kw.time.dt.year)['KWB'].transform('mean')
akwnb=monthlymean_kw.groupby(monthlymean_kw.time.dt.year)['KWNB'].transform('mean')
a_kwWan=monthlymean_kw.groupby(monthlymean_kw.time.dt.year)['KW_Wan'].transform('mean')

annualmean=pd.DataFrame({'year':list(year),'KW':list(a_kw),'KWB':list(a_kwb),'KWNB':list(akwnb),'KW_Wan':list(a_kwWan)},columns=['Year','KW','KWB','KWNB','KW_Wan'])
```

And it runs but I end up with a 396x5 DataFrame where each value is the mean of the year it was recorded. How do I create a DataFrame of the annual mean where there's only value per year?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Pandas Group by date using datetime data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39400115/python-pandas-group-by-date-using-datetime-data)

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
out = monthlymean_kw.groupby(monthlymean_kw["time"].dt.year)[monthlymean_kw.columns[1:]].agg("mean")
```