# df groupby for date, date yyyy-mm

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame for which I would like to group by 'acceptance date'. The date is yyyy-mm-dd and I would like to group it by yyyy-mm

```
df.groupby('Data przyjęcia')['NIP dłużnika'].count()
```

[out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df4K2.png)

I want to have values ​​​​counted for year-month

Comment: `df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(df['Data przyjęcia']).dt.to_period('M'))['NIP dłużnika'].count()`

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39400115/6151828

Comment: works as I wanted, thank you